# How is the Equals, GetHashCode, and Compare called from the following code? (Mystery)

Tags: c#

This code works but how does it not actual call any of the listed methods. It works but it seems like it is almost magic as to the hows and why does it work. I never actually call Equals, or GetHashCode, or Compare but the code works. I also never call anything in the constructor for the EmployeeComparer class that implements two interfaces.

**Question: Is this just done automatically when the class in instanciated with the new KeyWord?** (Some thing just doesn't seem right here)

```
        public class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>,
                                        IComparer<Employee>
```

### EmployeeComparer:

```
        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return String.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
        }
```

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate void Del(string e);
        Del handler = DelegateMethod;
        Dictionary<string, List<Employee>> d = new Dictionary<string, 
                                                              List<Employee>>();

        public static void DelegateMethod(string message)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(message);
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void testDel(Del d)
        {
            d.Invoke("L");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            //p.handler("Hello World");
            //p.handler("DisneyLand");
            //p.handler("Cattle Wars");
            //p.testDel(p.handler);
            var d = new SortedDictionary<string, SortedSet<Employee>>();
                                                               //Hashset no duplicates

            d.Add("AA", new SortedSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparer()));
            d["AA"].Add(new Employee { Name = "A" });
            d["AA"].Add(new Employee { Name = "B"} );
            d["AA"].Add(new Employee { Name = "C"} );
            d["AA"].Add(new Employee { Name = "C" });
            d["AA"].Add(new Employee { Name = "C" });

            d.Add("BB", new SortedSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparer()));
            d["BB"].Add(new Employee { Name = "E"} );
            d["BB"].Add(new Employee { Name = "F"} );
            d["BB"].Add(new Employee { Name = "A"} );

            d.Add("CC", new SortedSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparer()));
            d["CC"].Add(new Employee { Name = "Z"} );
            d["CC"].Add(new Employee { Name = "X"} );
            d["CC"].Add(new Employee { Name = "Y"} );

            d.Add("DD", new SortedSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparer()));
            d["DD"].Add(new Employee { Name = "Z" });
            d["DD"].Add(new Employee { Name = "U" });
            d["DD"].Add(new Employee { Name = "U" });
            d["DD"].Add(new Employee { Name = "Q" });
            d["DD"].Add(new Employee { Name = "Y" });

            foreach (var a in d)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.Key);
                foreach (var e in a.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + e.Name);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>, 
                                    IComparer<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeComparer() { }

        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return String.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code *should* be calling `Compare` (see +1 Servy's answer) - have you tried to set break point in the method?

Answer (score 5):

It's not magic at all. [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395024%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s implementation calls `Compare` (in your example, nothing calls `GetHashCode` or `Equals`). It's like if you do the following:

```
void Main()
{
    MyMethod(new EmployeeComparer());
}
void MyMethod(IComparer<Employee> comparer)
{
    var emp1 = new Employee { Name = "George" };
    var emp2 = new Employee { Name = "Tom" };
    Console.WriteLine(comparer.Compare(emp1, emp2));
}
```

From `Main`'s perspective, it never called `Compare`, it only did a `new`. The method it called is the one that did the `Compare`.

Answer (score 2):

The Equals(), Compare() and maybe GetHashCode() methods are called by the Dictionary classes.

> Question:  Is this just done automatically when the class in instanciated with the new KeyWord?

No, it is done (called) when you call `d.Add(...)`.

Comment: `Dictionary` will never call `Compare`.

Comment: @Servy - not even the SortedDictionary?

Comment: A `SortedDictionary` would not use `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, *only* `Compare`.  No type of dictionary would use all three.

Comment: But then the family of _Dictionary classes_ does use all three.

Comment: But he's not using the entire family of dictionaries.  (In which this object is the key.)

Comment: on "maybe GetHashCode" - "What is GetHashCode used for? It is by design useful for only one thing: putting an object in a hash table. Hence the name. " - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx  (`Dictionary` is one of "hash table" classes in .Net)